# Visual Studio can only debug code in safe mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I don't know why my VS2022 can't breakpoint debugging, can't single-step debugging, and it will automatically close VS2022 once debugging? Before I run VS2022 in safe mode, I can debug with breakpoints.

For example, debug in the following code:

```
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\Images\\test.png"));
src.StreamSource = ms;
src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
src.EndInit();

BitmapImage dest = new BitmapImage();
dest.BeginInit();
dest.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(new byte[src.StreamSource.Length], true);
src.StreamSource.CopyTo(dest.StreamSource);
dest.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
dest.EndInit();
```

Tried attaching to IIS process debugging but that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you performed a Repair-Install of VS? Have you filed a bug via _Help > Report a Problem_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first try to use the Visual Studio installation tool to repair Visual Studio and turn off the security software on the computer.

If it still doesn't work, follow the steps below:

1. Open the Registry Editor and find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
2. Right click on Lsa, point to New, and click DWORD Value
3. Type DisableLoopbackCheck and press Enter
4. Right click on "DisableLoopbackCheck" and click "Modify"
5. In the Value data box, type 1 and click OK
6. Still in the Registry Editor, find and click the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0
7. Right-click "MSV1_0", point to "New", and then click "Multiple String Value".
8. Type BackConnectionHostNames and press Enter.
9. Right-click on BackConnectionHostNames, and then click Modify.
10. In the Value data box, type one or more host names for the Web site on the local computer, and then click OK.
11. Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the IISAdmin service.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. The situation does ease for now, but it still exits during step-by-step debugging. I have decided to reinstall the system.